# how to add data to a column table from mysql function

Tags: mysql, sql, function

I want to add the return values of a function to a table's column 
It should all be in mysql no php 
I have a table with price,tax and price with tax I implemented the function to calculate the price with tax but I don't know how to add those values to that table

```
CREATE TABLE Faturat
(Fatura_ID varchar(10),
price real
,tax real,
CmimiMeTvsh real as (total(price,tax)),
Data varchar(20),
PRIMARY KEY (Fatura_ID));

drop function if exists  total;                             
delimiter //
create function total( x real, y real)
returns real
begin
   return X+x*Y/100;
   select fatura_id,total(price,tax)
   from FATURAT;


CREATE TRIGGER trgAuditOnInsertPunetoret AFTER INSERT ON faturat
FOR EACH ROW   
BEGIN     
INSERT INTO faturat
VALUES (fatura_id,price,tax,total(price,Tax),data);

end ;
delimiter //
```

Comment: Add table definitions, code, sample data and expected result. (Formatted text, not images.)

Comment: is tax an amount or  a rate? and have you read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html

Comment: Insert into YourTable (ColumnName) values ($returnvaluedata)

Comment: @jarlh I added the code and the insertion of data is price and tax should the  cmimimetvsh which meand pricewithtax be null when I insert data

Comment: @P.Salmon it's a rate 0.06 I wrote it in data as 6 in percentage  and made it 0.06 in the function code I tried  it as shown in code like the concat one you sent me but still don't get the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A generated column may be all you need here

```
drop table if exists t;

create table t(id int auto_increment primary key, price int, tax int, pricetax int as (price + price *tax/100));

insert into t (price,tax) values (100,6);

select * from t;

+----+-------+------+----------+
| id | price | tax  | pricetax |
+----+-------+------+----------+
|  1 |   100 |    6 |      106 |
+----+-------+------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

BTW From memory I don't think user defined functions are allowed in generated columns and your trigger won't work - you are not allowed to action the table which fired the trigger.

Comment: Yes I kept getting that error defined functions are not  allowed in generated columns , now I get the result, thank you.